# Cant Map() Through An Array Of Objects

Tags: node.js, arrays, object, ejs, array.prototype.map

Been trying to solve this one for quite a while now. I am saving an array which contains objects to my data base. When I try to `map()` through it to retrieve the object's properties, it's just rendering nothing.

This is the app.js code :

```
app.get("/:plasticcategory/product/:plasticproduct", (req, res) => {

   const plasticCategory = _.startCase(_.toLower(req.params.plasticcategory));

   const plasticProduct =  req.params.plasticproduct;

   Product.find({category: plasticCategory, title: plasticProduct},'alt', (err, foundItem) => {

     if(err){

       console.log(err)

     }else {

       console.log(foundItem);

      res.render('alternatives', {altProduct: foundItem});

     }

   });

 });
```

When I console.log(foundItem) the result is `[ { _id: 5f5f9b2a9f999b1e9009072b, alt: [ [Object] ] } ]`

This is my ejs code(trying to render the alt's array objects properties:

```
    <% altProduct.map(alt => {%>

     <div class="col-lg-3">

       <h1><%=alt.altTitle %></h1>

       <img src="<%=alt.altImage%>" alt="alt-image">

       <a href="<%=alt.altUrl %>">Get it now!</a>

     </div>

    <% }) %>
```

I have added images to make it more clear, thank you <3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLERR.png)

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(foundItem))`, to confirm that `foundItem` has the properties you expect?

Comment: Yeah it has the properties i expect, I checked it using console.log(JSON.stringify(foundItem) and via my mongoDB cluster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you render the template, I see you call it like this:

```
res.render('alternatives', {altProduct: foundItem});
```

Where `foundItem` is the array `[{ id: 'something', alt: [{ someObject }] }]`.

This is an array of results. Each of those results has a key called 'alt' with items in it. If you want to render all of those items together, you will need to compile them all into a single array. (This is called 'flat-mapping'.)

Starting inside the `else` block of the callback of `Product.find`:

```
const itemArrays = foundItem.map(item => item.alt); // Get the inner array from each result
const allAlternativeProducts = [].concat(...itemArrays); // Collect all these products into a single array
  res.render('alternatives', {altProduct: allAlternativeProducts});
```

Comment: Both solutions ends up with this error: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @IdanAtias Thanks, I misunderstood what the type of `foundItem` actually was. I've updated my answer completely.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am actually trying to render every single “alt” that matches the category and title specified by the URL, will it help if I’ll post the schema of the model?

Comment: Okay, so each of those 'alt' fields is itself a list of items, and each call to `Product.find` will retrieve multiple such lists. It sounds like there's a step where you will need to collect those lists together into a single list.

Comment: Rewrote the answer again.

Comment: Hey, glad I could help! :-)